# compare macro variable dates not working in sas

Tags: sas

I need help on comparing two macro variable dates. Below is the code. You can see by the log that MINDT_AS_DATE_MINUS_ONE_DT1 is 23JUL2012 and TESTDT1 is 01JAN2013. However, when comparing SAS says 23JUL2012 <01JAN2013. is FALSE. I am very confused. Thanks

```
%let TESTDT=2013-01-01;
%let TESTDT1=%sysfunc(inputn(&TESTDT, yymmdd10.), date9.);
%LET MINDT = 2012-07-23;
%LET MINDT_AS_DATE = %SYSFUNC(INPUTN(&MINDT., YYMMDD10.));
%LET MINDT_AS_DATE_MINUS_ONE = %SYSFUNC(INTNX(MONTHS, &MINDT_AS_DATE., -1));
%LET MINDT_AS_DATE_MINUS_ONE_DT = %SYSFUNC(INPUTN(&MINDT., YYMMDD10.));
data _null_;
MINDT_AS_DATE_MINUS_ONE_DT=&MINDT_AS_DATE_MINUS_ONE_DT.;
call symput('MINDT_AS_DATE_MINUS_ONE_DT1',put(MINDT_AS_DATE_MINUS_ONE_DT,date9.));
run;
%macro intermediate;
   %if &MINDT_AS_DATE_MINUS_ONE_DT1.<&TESTDT1. %then
      %do;      
     %PUT this is true;
      %end;
   %else 
      %do;
      %PUT this is false;
      %end;
%mend intermediate;
%intermediate;
```

Not working in LOG, See:

```
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable MINDT_AS_DATE_MINUS_ONE_DT1 resolves to 23JUL2012
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable TESTDT1 resolves to 01JAN2013
MLOGIC(INTERMEDIATE):  %IF condition &MINDT_AS_DATE_MINUS_ONE_DT1.<&TESTDT1. is FALSE
MLOGIC(INTERMEDIATE):  %PUT this is false
this is false
```

Comment: `23JUL2012` is greater than `01JAN2013` because you are comparing strings. Think of macro variables as snippets of code to be inserted somewhere in your program.

Comment: A more contrived example is that in macro you would also see `three < two` is evaluated to `TRUE` when the contextually driven mind does not understand why --`3 < 2` is obviously  `FALSE`, contrary to what macro is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props to Reeza

```
%macro intermediate;
    %if %sysevalf("&MINDT_AS_DATE_MINUS_ONE_DT1."d < "&TESTDT1."d) %then %do; 
        %PUT this is true;
    %end;
    %else %do;
        %PUT this is false;
    %end;
    %mend intermediate;

    %intermediate;
```